# Page not found error 404 django navbar link

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have an issue with the navbar link where it does find the html page ?

my mysite/urls.py

```
"""firt_website URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from pages import urls

app_name = 'pages'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),


]
```

my blog/urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='homepage'),
    path('education/', views.education, name='education'),
    path('experience/', views.experience, name='experience'),
    path('portfolio/', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
]
```

my navbar.html :

```
      <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container-collapse">
            <div class="u-align-center u-black u-container-style u-inner-container-layout u-opacity u-opacity-95 u-sidenav">
              <div class="u-sidenav-overflow">
                <div class="u-menu-close"></div>
                <ul class="u-align-center u-nav u-popupmenu-items u-unstyled u-nav-2"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Acceuil.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'main:experience' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Experience</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'main:education' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Study</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'main:portfolio' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Portfolio</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'main:homepage' %}#sec-1120" data-page-id="134427998" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Contact</a>
</li></ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-black u-menu-overlay u-opacity u-opacity-70"></div>
          </div>
```

my views :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import ContactForm

# Create your views here.


def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def education(request):
    return render(request, 'Education.html')


def experience(request):
    return render(request, 'Experience.html')


def portfolio(request):
    return render(request, 'Portfolio.html')
```

The struggle I have when I click on a link then the error of not finding the page or uploading the HTML page.

please find the example of it below in an image :

[image: error page 404 navbar link]

Do you know why even tho I have put "/" in blog/urls.py for each path ....?

Comment: You try to call the resource `Experience.html` but in your `urls.py` you haven't defined any match for this path.

Comment: Any links worked? Did you store your template on the right path? Why you declared the app name additionally in both `urls.py`?

Comment: You can remove `app_name` "pages" from your app's urls.py. You would only need in project's urls.py.

Comment: @Matthias i did as calling in blog/url.py  calling the views required for it?

Comment: @mhhabib i used to not have one then it was written error reverse match for my navbar then ?

Answer (score 0):

In your mysite/urls.py, try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from pages import urls

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Now if you go to e.g. 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/experience/ or click the nav button, it should hit the functions in your views.py.

Comment: I tried , first apparently importing the from pages imports urls seems to be not working